# How to upgrade MSbuild version in Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have an angular UI and API build which builds fine in local (Visual studio 2019). But in Azure pipeline it fails with below error. In pipeline tasks I cannot find any options to upgrade/downgrade the SDK version nor the MSBuild version. Definitely there should be an option somewhere I am unable to find. Can someone please throw some light?

```
 Error : Version 5.0.407 of the .NET Core SDK requires at least version 16.8.0 of MSBuild. The current available version of MSBuild is 15.9.21.664. Change the .NET Core SDK specified in global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version currently available.
```

Comment: Is the pipeline build machine made from a custom image?

Comment: I am new to Azure, probably not sure about your question. But if you are speaking about Agent pool, I am using a private agent pool not Hosted one.

Comment: Yes, this error is referring to the machine in the agent pool. You'll need to update that machine (or image if it's a scale set).

Comment: @ joelforsyth Thanks! I have tried from a different agent pool (i.e. previous image) and its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider adding this task in your pipeline:

```
UseDotNet@2
```

This pipeline task should update the .net version and, at the same time, update your version of MSBuild within the context of your build.

This is a basic example:

```
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      packageType: sdk
      version: 6.0.x
      includePreviewVersions: false
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/use-dotnet-v2?view=azure-pipelines

Answer (score 1):

> How to upgrade MSbuild version in Azure pipeline?

You need to update your Visual Studio version from 2017 to 2019.

.NET Core SDK versions `5.0.XXX` are intended to be used with Visual Studio 2019 and MSBuild `16.x`.

.NET Core SDK versions for Visual Studio 2017 are `2.2.1XX` and `2.1.5XX`.

You could check the document [Visual Studio SDKs](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks):

[image]

Comment: My pipeline uses latest Visual Studio version (i.e. 2022). But it still fails.

Comment: @Thiyagu, The version of the Visual Studio installed on your server is 2022?

Comment: Yes, on the server the version is latest (2022) only.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this? I can't find any information on upgrading my agent so that it can support .NET 7.